# Get the "furthest point away" along a B-Spline in a segment

Tags: geometry, interpolation, spline

Given a B-Spline define by n + 1 control points and degree p, and a specific "t" value segment between knots e.g. 0.6 <= t <+ 0.7, I need to find the point at which the B-Spline "bulges" the furthest away from the straight line between the knots i.e. the furthest distance perpendicular distance from the straight line that interpolates the two knots to any point on that segment.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Geometric solution: Draw parallel lines to the "straight line that interpolates the two knots" so that the parallel line has at least one point in common with the spline; then see which of those is the furthest away.

Comment: This seems like a good idea in practice, however I'm not sure how far away to draw my parallel line. How can I know when my parallel line is passing through my B Spline using a formula of some sort? @MattiP.

Comment: What do you know about the spline? Do you have an equation for it? Or a list of points?

Comment: @MattiP. I have an equation for it defined by the generic B-Spline equation found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline#Definition. This requires control points, knot values and the degree of the curve, which I indeed do have